# jQuery Range Slider - Swap Images due dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**I have the following issue:**

- I want to add an Range Slider
- By moving the trigger different images should appear

**The goal:**

- To combine the 2 Range Slider Examples to one!
- I want to have the design of the first Range Slider
- But with the function of the second Range Slider (the ability to change images)

Hope ya'll can help me - Cheers!

```css
.slider{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;position:relative}.slider.slider-horizontal{width:50%;height:20px}.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-track{height:5px;width:100%;margin-top:-3px;top:50%;left:0;     background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #D4D4D4 0%, #BDBDBD 100%);
    border: 0;
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 10px;
    transition: height .5s ease, opacity 1s ease;
    z-index: -20;}.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-selection,.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-track-low,.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-track-high{height:100%;top:0;bottom:0}.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-tick,.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-handle{margin-left:-10px}.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-tick.triangle,.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-handle.triangle{position:relative;top:50%;transform:translateY(-50%);border-width:0 10px 10px 10px;width:0;height:0;border-bottom-color:#2e6da4;margin-top:0}.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-tick-container{white-space:nowrap;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%}.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-tick-label-container{white-space:nowrap;margin-top:20px}.slider.slider-horizontal .slider-tick-label-container .slider-tick-label{padding-top:4px;display:inline-block;text-align:center}.slider.slider-horizontal.slider-rtl .slider-track{left:initial;right:0}.slider.slider-horizontal.slider-rtl .slider-tick,.slider.slider-horizontal.slider-rtl .slider-handle{margin-left:initial;margin-right:-10px}.slider.slider-horizontal.slider-rtl .slider-tick-container{left:initial;right:0}.slider.slider-vertical{height:210px;width:20px}.slider.slider-vertical .slider-track{width:10px;height:100%;left:25%;top:0}.slider.slider-vertical .slider-selection{width:100%;left:0;top:0;bottom:0}.slider.slider-vertical .slider-track-low,.slider.slider-vertical .slider-track-high{width:100%;left:0;right:0}.slider.slider-vertical .slider-tick,.slider.slider-vertical .slider-handle{margin-top:-10px}.slider.slider-vertical .slider-tick.triangle,.slider.slider-vertical .slider-handle.triangle{border-width:10px 0 10px 10px;width:1px;height:1px;border-left-color:#2e6da4;border-right-color:#2e6da4;margin-left:0;margin-right:0}.slider.slider-vertical .slider-tick-label-container{white-space:nowrap}.slider.slider-vertical .slider-tick-label-container .slider-tick-label{padding-left:4px}.slider.slider-vertical.slider-rtl .slider-track{left:initial;right:25%}.slider.slider-vertical.slider-rtl .slider-selection{left:initial;right:0}.slider.slider-vertical.slider-rtl .slider-tick.triangle,.slider.slider-vertical.slider-rtl .slider-handle.triangle{border-width:10px 10px 10px 0}.slider.slider-vertical.slider-rtl .slider-tick-label-container .slider-tick-label{padding-left:initial;padding-right:4px}.slider.slider-disabled .slider-handle{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#dfdfdf 0,#bebebe 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#dfdfdf 0,#bebebe 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#dfdfdf 0,#bebebe 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffdfdfdf',endColorstr='#ffbebebe',GradientType=0)}.slider.slider-disabled .slider-track{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#e5e5e5 0,#e9e9e9 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#e5e5e5 0,#e9e9e9 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#e5e5e5 0,#e9e9e9 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffe5e5e5',endColorstr='#ffe9e9e9',GradientType=0);cursor:not-allowed}.slider input{display:none}.slider .tooltip.top{margin-top:-36px}.slider .tooltip-inner{white-space:nowrap;max-width:none}.slider .hide{display:none}.slider-track{position:absolute;cursor:pointer;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5 0,#f9f9f9 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5 0,#f9f9f9 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#f5f5f5 0,#f9f9f9 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff5f5f5',endColorstr='#fff9f9f9',GradientType=0);-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);border-radius:4px}.slider-selection{position:absolute;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#f9f9f9 0,#f5f5f5 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#f9f9f9 0,#f5f5f5 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#f9f9f9 0,#f5f5f5 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff9f9f9',endColorstr='#fff5f5f5',GradientType=0);-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);box-shadow:inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;border-radius:4px}.slider-selection.tick-slider-selection{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#8ac1ef 0,#82b3de 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#8ac1ef 0,#82b3de 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#8ac1ef 0,#82b3de 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff8ac1ef',endColorstr='#ff82b3de',GradientType=0)}.slider-track-low,.slider-track-high{position:absolute;background:transparent;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;border-radius:4px}.slider-handle{position:absolute;top:0;width:20px;height:20px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.31);
    background: #d4d4d4;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #EFEFEF, #bbbbbb);
    background-size: auto 60px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: box-shadow 0.1s linear, background-position 0.1s linear;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #1B1E28 15%, #e94843 100%);
    height: 38px;
    left: -18px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -6px;
    width: 32px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);}.slider-handle.round{border-radius:}.slider-handle.triangle{background:transparent none}.slider-handle.custom{background:transparent none}.slider-handle.custom::before{line-height:20px;font-size:20px;content:'\2605';color:#726204}.slider-tick{position:absolute;width:2px;height:20px;background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#aeaeae 0,#d1d1d1 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#f9f9f9 0,#f5f5f5 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,##afafaf 0,#d1d1d1 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fff9f9f9',endColorstr='#fff5f5f5',GradientType=0);box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;filter:none;opacity:1;border:0 solid transparent}.slider-tick.round{border-radius:}.slider-tick.triangle{background:transparent none}.slider-tick.custom{background:transparent none}.slider-tick.custom::before{line-height:20px;font-size:20px;content:'\2605';color:#726204}.slider-tick.in-selection{background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#8ac1ef 0,#d1d1d1 100%);background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#8ac1ef 0,#d1d1d1 100%);background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,#afafaf 0,#82b3de 100%);background-repeat:repeat-x;filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#8ac1ef',endColorstr='#afafaf',GradientType=0);opacity:1}



.slider-handle:after {
    content:"";
    border-left: 1px solid #17181E;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 8px 2px;

}

.slider-handle span {
    border-left: 1px solid #17181E;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 8px 2px;
}

.slider-handle::after span {
    border-left: 1px solid #17181E;
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    display: inline-block;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 8px 2px;
}

.range-slider {
margin-left: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-slider/9.9.0/bootstrap-slider.min.js"></script>


<h3> Main Slider </h3>

<div class="range-slider">
<span id="ex18-label-1" class="hidden"></span>
        <input id="ex19" type="text"
              data-provide="slider"
              data-slider-ticks="[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]"
              data-slider-ticks-labels='["phase 1", "phase 2", "phase 3", "phase 4", "phase 5"]'
              data-slider-min="1"
              data-slider-max="5"
              data-slider-step="1"
              data-slider-value="1"
              data-slider-tooltip="hide"  />
              
              </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            
 <h3> Image Slider </h3>
           
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="slider" value="0.0" min="0" max="5" step="1" />
<br /><br />
<img src="" style='width:100px;height:100px;' id='img'/>
slider value = <span id="sliderStatus">0</span>
      
              
              
              <script>var imageUrl = new Array();

        imageUrl[0] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg';

        imageUrl[1] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg';

        imageUrl[2] = 'http://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dahlia-flowers.jpg';

        imageUrl[3] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/39517/rose-flower-blossom-bloom-39517.jpeg';

        imageUrl[4] = 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/36764/marguerite-daisy-beautiful-beauty.jpg';

        imageUrl[5] = 'http://cdn2.stylecraze.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/dahlia-flowers.jpg';
       
$(document).on('input change', '#slider', function() {//listen to slider changes
    var v=$(this).val();//getting slider val
   $('#sliderStatus').html( $(this).val() );
  $("#img").prop("src", imageUrl[v]);
});</script>
```